# Some grid lines, varying thickness, with Java SWT

Tags: java, layout, widget, swt

I have seen other questions about having lines in a composite widget with grid layout, but I'd like to have lines only in some places, and I'd like to have occasional thicker (2-pixel) lines. Something like this: [image]

The widgets in the grid will mostly be canvas, also labels (or something else with text, not sure yet).

My current idea is that each of the widgets in the grid has a line on the bottom and on the right, so widgets in certain columns would have a thicker line on the right and widgets in certain rows would have a thicker line underneath. But is there a better (neater or more efficient) way to do it?

Comment: You might want to look at a table control, maybe Eclipse Nebula [tag:nattable] https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. What's "table control"? NatTable looks like an overkill for my purpose. Making sure to add all packages on which it depends. Adding the NatTable package. Adding the Eclipse plugin for it (?) Getting a widget with tons of features, out of which I'd use hardly anything. All the layers from an array to display unused, for example. It feels like it would clutter my project with loads of unnecessary stuff. However, I recognise it's a great and powerful tool, just not for my project.

Comment: I just meant some sort of control (like NatTable) that implements a table. You can set up `Table` so that you draw everything yourself using SWT.EraseItem, SWT.MeasureItem, SWT.PaintItem listeners.